# リストのループにおける要素入れ替えの挙動について

Tags: python

次の2つのpythonコードの挙動の違いについて理解できず、困っています。
次のプログラムはタプルのリストの二重ループに対し、要素の大小を比較して入れ替えるプログラムです

```
pair = [(1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 2) ]
for a1,b1 in pair:
    for a2,b2 in pair:
        print( a1,b1,'-', a2,b2)
        if a1>a2:
            a1,a2 = a2,a1
        if b1>b2:
            b1,b2 = b2,b1
print( pair )

結果
1 1 - 1 1
1 1 - 3 2
1 1 - 2 2
3 2 - 1 1
1 1 - 3 2
1 1 - 2 2
2 2 - 1 1
1 1 - 3 2
1 1 - 2 2
[(1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 2)]
```

一方で中間の変数をa1,a2,b1,b2を別の変数にコピーして同じを処理をすると、ループの巡り方が全く変わります。

```
pair = [(1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 2)]
for a1,b1 in pair:
    for a2,b2 in pair:
        ca1,ca2,cb1,cb2 = a1,a2,b1,b2
        print( ca1,cb1,'-',ca2,cb2 )
        if ca1>ca2:
            ca1,ca2 = ca2,ca1
        if cb1>cb2:
            cb1,cb2 = cb2,cb1
print( pair )

結果
1 1 - 1 1
1 1 - 3 2
1 1 - 2 2
3 2 - 1 1
3 2 - 3 2
3 2 - 2 2
2 2 - 1 1
2 2 - 3 2
2 2 - 2 2
[(1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 2)]
```

処理後にいずれもリストpairについて破壊的な変更は行われていませんが、ループ中での挙動では変数の直接入れ替えた場合、リストのループの挙動が変更されているように見えます。

今のところa1,a2,b1,b2あるいはca1,ca2,cb1,cb2の各変数のいずれもがpairのタプルの各要素への参照を保持していて、入れ替えではその「変数への参照」そのものを入れ替えており、pairそのものは変更されずに保持されている、と理解していますが、なぜリストのループの挙動が一方では代わり、一方では変わらないのでしょうか。

何かヒントがありましたら、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 内側のループ内で外側の変数 `a1`, `b1` を変更したかどうかが異なります。「変数への参照」という表現から, なにか誤解があるのかも

Comment: 後のコードでは `ca1, cb1` を元の `a1, b1` の値で毎回リセットしています。

Comment: oririさん、metropolisさん、コメントありがとうございました、納得しました。たしかに外側のループ変数を内側で書き換えてループ順を替えていることを意識できてませんでした。```ca1, cb1```の値も確かに毎回リセットしてますね…